# Laptop RAM Upgradation Parameters

Tags: memory

I have 2 gb DDR3  1333mhz laptop ram and i want to buy another 4 gb ram DDR3 of 1333mhz but of differnt brand . so is it ok if only frequencies of 2 rams are matching or do i need to look into another parameters of RAM?
I mean matching frequencies is suffice, even though brands are differnt?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Short Answer: No.

Longer answer: Frequency isn't the only thing you need to worry about.

Mismatched capacities will result in both sticks running in single channel mode, even with matching brands, resulting in decreased performance.

CAS latency, Voltages, Capacity, Frequency are all things needed to be considered.

Repeating what other people have said before in other questions, It is easiest to just buy matching RAM rather than deal with the headache of matching RAM.